Как лучше хранить маловесные данные в чат-боте? Python Django
Пишу чат-бот для ТГ используя telebot и django. У меня есть бэк с бд п постгресе и я делаю так, чтобы бот присылал не новое сообщение, а обновлял старое при возможности. Для этого я написал функцию (сейчас она кривовата, оптимизирую пока что, так как есть некоторые неудобства с API телеги) которая получает изначальные аргументы сообщения и не присылает новое, а меняет старое. Для этого мне у каждого юзера необходимо хранить id сообщения которое сейчас у него "основное". сейчас у меня есть словарь, в котором по ключу-id юзера хранится id его сообщения, а так же в мой бд хранится id сообщения в отдельном поле (для того, что бы при перезагрузке бота или сервера или еще по какой-то причине этот словарь обновился, я всё равно мог получить id из базы), а сам словарь я сделал что бы не лазить каждый раз в бд, при каждом изменении сообщения.
Вопрос следующий. Насколько это хорошее решение, потому что ощущение что я навесил костыль над костылём, было бы проще просто хранить в бд, я из бота туда запрос делаю напрямую из ОРМ джанго. Или мб есть какая то библиотека доп для хранения такого словарика в json, например.

Попробуй использовать reddis для кеширования, а хранить все в постгресе.
